# Java "abstract like" method with body

Tags: java, class, methods, abstract, inheritance

there are the following classes:

```
public abstract class Super
{
    public abstract void run();
}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        System.out.println("Method called");
        System.out.println("Sub1 called");
    }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        System.out.println("Method called");
        System.out.println("Sub2 called");
    }
}
```

how can I avoid that I have to write the "System.out.println("Method called");" two times?

Thank you for answers

CalibeR.50

Comment: If every implementation is same , then why do you abstract the method .

Comment: Can you show us how the `run()` method is called ?

Comment: this is just an example, there will be more code in the run methods in Sub1 and Sub2.

Comment: @Guillaume Darmont: No sorry, I don't have coded it yet. Just want to know if something like that is possible so I know how I can code it

Comment: Then you can have a method with the common code in super class , and call it from subclass !

Comment: @The New Idiot: But then you don't have to implement it in the sub classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bring the common functionality to the superclass, and define another abstract method, for which the subclasses will define their own implementation.

```
public abstract class Super {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Method called");
        printMessage();
    }
    abstract void printMessage ();
}

public class Sub1 extends Super {
    @Override
    void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Sub1 called");
    }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super {
    @Override
    void printMessage () {
        System.out.println("Sub2 called");
    }
}
```

This way you can avoid the duplication of calling the common method of the superclass twice.

Comment: But I am not able to make the method "printMessage" private. Is it possible to only make "run" callable in your example?

Comment: @CalibeR.50 If it is private, it will not be accessible from the superclass. However, you can make it *package private*, by omitting the access level modifier, and it will be visible only within the package

Comment: Oh, forgot about protected. I'll try if this works in my case. Thank you

Comment: Isn't it possible to really force that the code in run is executed? So it isn't possible to only call "printMessage", but only "run"?

Comment: @CalibeR.50 From within the same package, `printMessage()` will be visible... From outside the package though, only `run()` will be available.

Comment: Hope you will get this, since it's rather old. 
Does this approach have a common name? Or could you even call it a design pattern?

Comment: @bdvlop: Not very good with design patterns, but In [bzzzrd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17506555/828193) he calls it the "Template Method Pattern".

Answer (score 4):

You can put run() implementation into the abstract class:

```
// Super is still an abstract class
public abstract class Super
{
    // While method run is not an abstract method:
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Method called");
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
  // There's no need of declaring run() here unless you want to change its behaviour
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
}
```

In the edited version of your question, you can just use an inherited run realization

```
// Super is still abstract
public abstract class Super
{
    // But method run is not abstract
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Method called");
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
      super.run(); // <- call Super.run() that prints "Method called"
      System.out.println("Sub1 called");
  }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
      super.run();
      System.out.println("Sub2 called");
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to make clear what I am trying to do exactly

Comment: you also need to call super.run() if you choose to override that method in Sub1 and Sub2

Comment: But now you could forget to call super.run(). Is it possible to force this call like abstract forces to override the method?

Comment: @CalibeR.50 No, you can't force to call super.run() unless you write super.run(). The reasons are: in some cases you should totally override a method, so you should not call super.run() at all; in many other cases it may occure that you have to call super.run(), say, in the very end of the method or you should call super.run() twice etc.

Comment: Forcing subclasses to call the super implementation is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super).

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Template Method Pattern":

```
public class Super
{
    public void template() {
        System.out.println("Method called");
        run();
    }

    public abstract void run();
}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run () // out called before run
    {

    }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run () // out called before run
    {

    }
}
```

Aditionally you can make run protected.

Answer (score 3):

If part of the implementation of `run()` is common to both Sub1 and Sub2, I suggest you simply use inheritance and override run in the subclasses. Here's the code example:

```
public abstract class Super
{
    public void run() {
        // Code shared by all subclasses
        System.out.println("Method called");
    }

}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        super.run();
        System.out.println("Sub1 called");
    }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        super.run();
        System.out.println("Sub2 called");
    }
}
```

The trick here is that the `Super` class can be defined `abstract` while implementing methods. If you have subclasses that do not need the shared code, you can override `run()` without the `super.run()` code and change it all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the common code in super class method and call it from sub class methods .

```
public abstract class Super
{
   public abstract void run();
   // code common to both the sub classes implemented
   public void print() {
     System.out.println("Method called");
   }
}

public class Sub1 extends Super
{
   @Override
   public void run ()
   {
     print();
     System.out.println("Sub1 called");
     // sub class specific code here
   }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super
{
   @Override
   public void run ()
   {
      print();
      System.out.println("Sub2 called");
      // sub class specific code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Jeah, this would work. But isn't there a possibility to force that the code is executed with "run"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all subclasses to have identical behavior, then the correct technique would be to code the method in the superclass only, allowing the subclasses to inherit it. But that would eliminate the need for your superclass to be abstract in this case, since it'll implement its only method.

Comment: I'll edit the example a bit to make clear what I am trying to do